# remove .animation on blur for my function

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-animate, parent, margins

I have this function on which I put a parent class in order to have a margin-right for the input parent. I want to modify a little bit parent behaivior and to replace this "`$(this).parent().addClass('cooling');`" with "
`$(this).parent().animate({ marginRight: "200px" }, slow );`" but I dont know how to remove that animate margin right on blur. If anyone can help me ...

```
function inputWidth(){
   $('input[type=text]')
.focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 21) {
        $(this).data('default', $(this).data('default') || $(this).width());
        $(this).stop().animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
        $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
        //$(this).parent().animate({ marginRight: "200px" }, slow );
    }
})
.blur(function() { /* lookup the original width */
    $(this).stop().animate({width: 
    $(this).data('default')},'fast');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('cooling');
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead .focus and .blur try:

.live('mouseover',function()) and .live('mouseout',function()) ... .stop() on the right selector should do what you want. search for another reason in your code why this is not working. cant see any problem why it should not work.

post edited!